# get_the_categories filter returns an empty array

Tags: categories, filters

I'm developing a theme that uses the `get_the_category_list()` function (in *category-template.php*).

Examining its code, this function calls the `get_the_category()` function (in *category-template.php*) which applies the `get_the_categories` filter at the end:

```
return apply_filters( 'get_the_categories', $categories );
```

For some strange reason, this filter returns an empty array. If I replace this line with:

```
return $categories;
```

then everything is ok.

Any ideas about what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes occur when a filter is [*applied*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters), but's that's not where the rules for the alteration originate from.

Either your theme or a plugin you are using must be [*hooking*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) into that filter and be [*adding*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) a callback function/method, that is responsible for the `$categories` array being emptied.

Deactivate all plugins, switch to a standard theme. Things should be back to normal. Reactivate everything one by one and find the culprit.

Alternatively,

```
cd /path/to/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ && grep -r 'get_the_categories' .
```

from a *nix shell should also help you find it.